# How to convert my server time to usertimezone using timezone JS

Tags: javascript

Actually, I have this below lines of code, Is this below lines of code right to convert my date to another format

```
var dateObj = new timezoneJS.Date("2018-03-12 18:18:26", "America/Los_Angeles");
dateObj.setTimezone(varyingtimezone);
var userTimeZoneDate = filterDate(dateObj._dateProxy,'MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a');
```

Comment: Aside from this snippet, you should always store and communicate using UTC timestamps. That way you avoid having to do double conversions and there can never be any confusion about dates and time in your database and code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this.

Comment: Whenever you store or exchange a date somewhere, you always store/exchange it in the UTC timezone. Postpone timezone translations to the very end, like when displaying it to a user. From your snippet I derived that you are storing/retrieving timestamps in the "America/Los_Angeles" timezone, that should be UTC instead. Rule of thumb I just came up with: "Convert timestamps to UTC as soon as possible, keep in UTC for as long as possible".